# Unable to perform initial commit using GitHub Windows App

Tags: git, github

So I created a repository in my Visual Studio project directory. On my initial commit the 2 standard git files were pushed to the repo but nothing else. There are 1968 Changes sitting in the changes section but the button to Commit to master is grayed out. I am unable to make a pull request. That button is greyed out as well. All I can click is Sync which says everything is up to do. I also tried to manually commit using the console but it says everything is up to date. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Do you have access to the Git bash in Windows?  Open it, change to the root of your project directory, and then type `git status`.  What does this show you?

Comment: It lists all the files as New File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type something in the "Summary" section it should turn darker and allow you to "Commit to master".

Comment: Wow that was simple, can't believe I didn't think to try that thanks

Comment: I had the exact same "encephalo-flatulence" myself!